# Future of future in Java

Tags: java, future

I have a method `doAsync` which returns me a future.
I want to start this method in the future, so I'm using a `ScheduledExecutorService`.

I would like to have a `Future` which completes when the `runAsync()` method has finished to run.

Basically, my code looks like:

```
public Future scheduleAsyncTask(int delay){
    return this.scheduledExecutorService.schedule(()->runAsync(),delay,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS); 
}
```

This does not work properly since the future returned completes when the scheduled task starts running, but not when it's done.

How can I solve my issue?

Comment: Why do you need to start the future returned from runAsync() per scheduledExecutorService.schedule()? It wont be running in a Thread provided by scheduledExecutorService anyway.

Comment: And regardless, heed your compiler warnings and use proper generics on `Future`.

Answer (score 0):

```
return scheduler.schedule(() -> runAsync().get(delay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS), delay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```